# Replacing letter from a paragraph

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to replace a letter from a paragraph I have added this code mentioned below its working but its replacing only one letter in the paragraph, For example I have this paragraph

`This is a test paragraph, This is a test paragraph, This is a test paragraph`

Now in the above line I am trying to replace "test" with "new" my code only works for first test other remains the same as test, Can someone guide me how can I replace every "test" element with the new text I want within the paragraph?

Code I am using:

```
jQuery(".bizinfo h4").text(function () {
    return jQuery(this).text().replace("test", ", "); 
});
```

Comment: Doing `jQuery(this).text()` inside a `.text()` callback misses half the point of passing a callback to `.text()` in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need a regular expression (denoted by `/  /` delimiters) with the `g` (global) flag set to pick up all the matches:

```js
jQuery(".bizinfo h4").text(function () {
    return jQuery(this).text().replace(/test/g, ", "); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bizinfo"><h4>This is a test paragraph, This is a test paragraph, This is a test paragraph</h4></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `/test/g` in your function in order to replace letter from a paragraph

```
jQuery(".bizinfo h4").text(function () {
    return jQuery(this).text().replace(/test/g, ", "); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2nd [text function](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function) argument and [`g` global match regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Parameters) parameter like:

```
jQuery(".bizinfo h4").text(function (index, text) {
     return text.replace(/test/g, ", "); 
});
```